# cout does not print even with time delay

Tags: c++, time, cout, endl

I expect `cout` to print "hello" and two seconds later " world".

```
int t = time( NULL );

std::cout << "hello";

while( time(NULL) < (t + 2) );

std::cout << " world";
```

But instead, `cout` prints noting to screen until after two seconds later, then the program prints "hello world". Even if the time delay increases like `(t + 9)`, it is the same result. I Am not familiar with this `cout` behaviour.

But if I add `std::endl` at the first `cout` like so:

```
std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
...
```

I get the expected result "hello" and two seconds later " world ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cout` is usually buffered, meaning it may not output immediately unless you force it to.  Try [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) after your first output:

```
std::cout << "hello " << std::flush;
```

Comment: The reason why `std::endl` works is that it flushes the stream exactly like `std::flush` does. Also using `std::cerr` always flushes instantly AFAIK.